# How to add custom fields to woocommerce shop page with acf

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'am having some difficulties in order to integrate advanced custom fields to the woocommerce shop page.
My code is a repeater field and I need to add it to the top of the shop page, but this is not working.
I've already tried by adding the page id and nothing happens. 
Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

I've created a woocommerce folder inside my child theme, and I am trying to add this code to the archive-product.php template.

```
<div class="container accueil">

        <h2 class="titre-section">Tous nos saveurs à un seul clic !</h2>

        <div class="row products-categories">

            <?php if( have_rows('categories_menu') ): ?>



                <?php while( have_rows('categories_menu') ): the_row(); 

                    // vars
                    $titre = get_sub_field('titre_categorie');
                    $image = get_sub_field('image_categorie');
                    ?>
                    <a class="link-cat" href="/carte/">
                    <div class="col-md-4 product-cat" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);">
                        <h2 class="cat-title"><?php echo $titre; ?></h2>    
                    </div>
                    </a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't have error messages.

Comment: We need to check your code first (thanks for editing) but what I can tell now is that your french sentence "Tous nos saveurs à un seul clic !" is almost correct but not totally. It seems automatically translated or something.

"Toutes nos saveurs en un seul clic !" would be more appropriated.

Comment: Are you sure the `categories_menu` field name is correct and that it has a value? do a `print_r(get_field('categories_menu'))` and post the output

Comment: also, you may want to do a `print_r(get_the_ID())` right before your `if( have_rows('categories_menu') )` to confirm that the ID of the page you added the field value to is the same as the one inside the PHP you have for retrieving the field.

Comment: Everything seems to be ok

Comment: If I add a simple custom field as a text or image with the page id, it works, but the problem is with the group and repeater fields, it is not  taking the sub-fields's values.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get Woo-commerce Shop Page ID then pass those ID to each get_field & rows

```
<?php if(is_shop()){ ?>
<div class="container accueil">

        <h2 class="titre-section">Tous nos saveurs à un seul clic !</h2>

        <div class="row products-categories">

            <?php $post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ); ?>

            <?php if( have_rows('categories_menu', $post_id) ): ?>

                <?php while( have_rows('categories_menu', $post_id) ): the_row(); 

                    $titre = get_sub_field('titre_categorie', $post_id);
                    $image = get_sub_field('image_categorie', $post_id);
                    ?>
                    <a class="link-cat" href="/carte/">
                    <div class="col-md-4 product-cat" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);">
                        <h2 class="cat-title"><?php echo $titre; ?></h2>    
                    </div>
                    </a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi there, 

Thanks a lot for your help, i'll try that.